# Flutter How to remove white blank between sliverappbar and sliverList when pull down sliverlist?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I'd like to do sync pull down for SliverAppBar together with SliverList but when pull down the SliverList, there comes a white blank between these 2 widgets.

Does anyone knows how to remove the padding between them? Thanks a lot.

What I mean is how to set SliverAppBar and SliverList always stick to each other.

```
Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(controller: controller, slivers: [
      SliverAppBar(
        // pinned: true,
        // floating: true,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            background: HomeTopBar(
              picHeightExtra: picHeightExtra,
              fitMode: fitMode,
            )),
        expandedHeight: 500 + picHeightExtra,
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
          return Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          );
        }, childCount: 30, addRepaintBoundaries: false),
      ),
    ]));
```

[image for SliverAppBar and SliverList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48VfX.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

finally find the answer...

Need to change the physics for CustomScrollView to ClampingScrollPhysics and there will be no blank for the "at top" widget.